# Include a fadeIn(Slow) on this changeable background Image javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript code to change the background image randomly and works fine, but is very rough. I would like to make some kind of transition between images, I would like to use fadeIn(slow) but don't know how to incorporate it to my code, can someone help me? Cheers!

JAVASCRIPT

```
window.onload = function () {
 // Array of Images
  var backgroundImg=["https://image1.com",
                    "https://image2.com",
                    "https://image3.com",
                    "https://image4.com"
                    ]

    setInterval(changeImage, 5000);
   function changeImage() {   
    var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));

    document.getElementById("sectionAbout").style.backgroundImage = "url('"+backgroundImg[i]+"')";

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution is to pass the transition handling to your browser, and all you should care about is the background changing.

Say we want to animate the body background.

Here's working example with colors, but can be done with images as well just use `backgroundImage` insead of `backgroundColor`

```js
var arr = ['blue', 'red', 'pink', 'yellow', 'brown']
var i = 0;
document.getElementById('l').addEventListener('click', function() {

  document.body.style.backgroundColor = arr[i];
  i++
  if (i == arr.length)
    i = 0;
});
```

```css
body {
  transition: background ease 2s;
}
```

```html
<button id="l">OK</button>
```

**EDIT : In case of Images, You would want to avoid, the jerky animations caused by the images not being loaded.**

```js
var arr = ["https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRyB57zuc4bms-hDtWMa-4BZvscIlJDm4r7a9WLaO4SAxUvKM-DDA", "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQBinSpWOvAtkxjmkf709O3rjH2ObRbWAEn9s0JcWaeL6LMtCbOrQ", "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRKY4J2qIFqkuDnABMzeypywbMSZL1cleS8vpySz0KD02wOYORU1g", "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRQkdQT0zN0xDVP-VuvwojSbS5dOstX14eZvJCOWNPxKJ5dWTIc"];
var i = 1;
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + img.src + ')';
  i++;
  if (i == arr.length)
    i = 0;
  setTimeout(function() {
    img.src = arr[i];
  }, 5000);
};

img.src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRyB57zuc4bms-hDtWMa-4BZvscIlJDm4r7a9WLaO4SAxUvKM-DDA";
```

```css
body {
  transition: background ease 2s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ZohirSalak CeNa but I don't want to click a button:( I just want to make it automatic

Comment: I updated my code based on your explanation but doesn't seem to work:( https://jsfiddle.net/ss3a5t2L/7/ can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? @ZohirSalak CeNa thanks

Comment: @Eugenio I updated the answer, with a workaround the images not being loaded in time and the jerky animation.

Comment: According to the specifications background-image is not an animatable property (see here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/#animatable-properties). Chrome currently supports it but Firefox follows the specs and so might future editions of Chrome, who knows? A safer and future proof way is to animate it yourself (see my answer).

Comment: I've changed it from the body to a specific div and works fine:)! Now I'm trying to understand what you did, not an expert and I really want to learn!! thanks @ZohirSalak CeNa

Comment: It's pretty easy to understand, i'll leave it to you to figure out :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `https://greensock.com/gsap`, it is really efficient in transitions and animation handling. Many experts use it for efficient transition or animation management.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the backgroundImage via javascript the image is loaded the moment the script is executed, so there will be a noticable lag. A solution is to load the images in css or to preload via js.

In below solution I added the images via css so there is no lag. Because Firefox doesn't support transition of background-image the script z-indexes the images in the right order and fades them (with a css animation on opacity).

html:

```
<div id="sectionAbout">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#sectionAbout {
  height: 100vh;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
}

.fadeIn {
  animation: fadeIn 2s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.img:nth-of-type(1) {
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url(http://picsum.photos/400/300?image=1);
}

etc..
```

js:

```
var imgDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".img");

setInterval(changeImage, 2000);
var i = 0;

function changeImage() {
    i++;
  el = imgDivs[i%4];
  el.classList.remove("fadeIn");
  // force css animation restart
  // (https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/)
  void el.offsetWidth;
  el.style.zIndex = i;
  el.classList.add("fadeIn"); 
}
```

For a working example see here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/tfc0kyp3/3/

Comment: not sure why but is not working on my computer and coded design:( @metatron but seems to be a good solution!